# UWP Hub equivalent on Android (xamarin native)

Tags: android, xamarin, uwp

I'm porting a UWP (win 10 app) to Xamarin (Android - maybe iOS).
The main screen uses a hub (horizontal)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/hub

On "large" devices it is nothing more than a scroll viewer.
On "small" (Windows mobile) devices it is also a scroll viewer. But it places sections when the users scrolls. So if the user scrolls just a little bit to the left the view scrolls back to the first section. If the user scrolls a bit more the second section.
Last not least - if the users scrolls over the last section the first comes in.
Or the other way - if I scroll from the first section to the right - I get the last section.

Is there an equivalent control available for Android (iOS)?

Comment: A pre-built equivalent? No, but using an iOS collection view with a subclassed `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and Android's RecyclerView with a custom `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` (something like `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`) can provide a similar user experience. It just depends upon how far from the standard platform experience you want to deviate and how much code you want to write ;-)

Comment: Hi, best would be a free library having such a control. Code fragments (xamarin C#) would also be an option.